# What does the Curly brackets in config files denote

Tags: c#, configuration, web-config

In my project config files there is a line

```
 <add key="ExceptionMessage" value="The Party360 service encountered an error while processing the request. The issue reference number is {Party360ExceptionID}."/>
```

I want to know what is the purpose of placing curly brackets outside Party360ExcetpionID, is the Party360ExcetpionID is a variable in which dynamic values are coming during runtime? If yes, can we check from where does this value is getting updated?

Comment: It looks like string interpolation syntax, except string interpolation has to be worked over at compile time to actually work - so it's *probably* someone's manual runtime implementation of string interpolation. Not something framework supplied and so we can't help you further.

Comment: That's what my first thought was, but i didn't find any examples which suggest that we can place string interpolation in config files.

Comment: Can you include the code that reads from and uses the `ExceptionMessage` config setting?

Comment: @mjwills i didnt know what code is using this `ExceptionMessage` setting, i just saw this  setting written in config file when i was updating another setting in config file, is there any way through which we can check what code is using this setting?